# Я хочу знать, какой пользователь написал какое сообщение в боте (pyTelegrambotAPI)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я написал бота, который измеряет площадь прямоугольника с помощью библиотеки pytelegrambotapi. Когда бот использует только один пользователь, бот возвращает правильный ответ, но когда несколько пользователей используют бота одновременно, бот путает ответы и приводит к неправильным ответам. Как узнать, какой пользователь написал какое сообщение?

```
a = ''
b = ''
float_pattern = r'^\d{1,7}\.\d{1,2}$'
...
...

def firstside(message):
    global a
    if message.text.isdigit() or re.match(float_pattern, message.text):
        a = float(message.text)
        print('a:', a, type(a))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "good!")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, secondside)
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Only number!")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, firstside)


def secondside(message):
    global b
    if message.text.isdigit() or re.match(float_pattern, message.text):
        a = float(message.text)
        print('b:', b, type(b))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "result = " +
        f'{eval(str(a*b))})
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Only number!")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, firstside)
```

Comment: У каждого пользователя телеграмма есть уникальный id

Comment: Вы как-то сильно замудрили код для простого подсчёта площади, вы так не думаете?

Comment: @arnold это просто для примера. Мой цель учиться user_id